# Use ERROR in if statement of SAS

Tags: sas

I just wrote a macro which to sign on to a remote server, of course a simple macro

```
%macro sign(servername);
%put                                                         ;
%put *********   You are now entering the server   ********* ;
%put *********                                     ********* ;


signon &servername user=_promopt_ password=_prompt_;

%if error %then

%put There is a problem in logging in;

%else 


%put *********                                     ********* ;
%put *********                                     ********* ;
%put *********   You are now ready to use server   ********* ;
%put *********                                     ********* ;
%put *********                                     ********* ;
%mend;
```

SO here I want to just put something in log saying if it throws an error for whatsoever reason., that may be wrong password or connection or anything, I want to print a statement with the help of %Put but not sure how.

Comment: What we used to do to test if a remote session was working was to rsubmit code that would use sysrput to change the setting of a macro variable in the local SAS session.

Comment: Hi Tom, 
I just want to use a put statement to print some lines I want if the login doesnt go through for any reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the CMACVAR option on the SIGNON statement.

```
signon &servername user=_promopt_ password=_prompt_ cmacvar=cerror;
%if &cerror %then
```

> CMACVAR=value
>
> specifies the name of the macro variable in which SAS stores a code indicating the state of the current sign-on. When a SIGNON is executed, SAS checks the state of the sign-on and stores a return code of 0, 1, or 2 in the specified CMACVAR variable.
>
> The return code is generated after SIGNON processing is complete and the name that you specify becomes the default name for the current server session.. The CMACVAR macro variable can then be programmatically queried to learn the processing status of the sign-on (completed, failed, or in progress). See CMACVAR Macro Variable Values in SIGNON for a description of what each return code means.
>
> ```
> CMACVAR Macro Variable Values in SIGNON
> Value Description
> 0 The sign-on is complete.
> 1 The sign-on failed.
> 2 You have already signed on to the current server session.
> 3 The sign-on is in progress.
> ```
>
> Note: If the SIGNON command or statement fails because of incorrect syntax, the macro variable is not set.

Comment: WOW this is what I am looking for, thanks a lot TOM.